# What is a saprotrophic mushroom?

Tags: mushrooms

I was [reading a post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/22837/can-oyster-mushrooms-grow-on-a-yucca-tree) about a Yucca having one these mushrooms grow on it.

The OP mentioned that the Yucca appeared to be on its way out after discovering the mushroom.

What do these mushrooms do that can be fatal to a host?

What part of the world are these mushrooms indigenous to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of mushrooms, [saprotrophic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saprotrophic_nutrition) just means that the fungus uses already dead or dying plant material for sustenance.

This is in contrast to parasitic fungi, which will actually hasten the death of their host plants; for example [ganoderma zonatum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganoderma_zonatum), or [reishi mushroom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lingzhi_mushroom).

Your trees and landscaping are not really threatened by saprotrophic fungi unless they are already sick or dying, which can happen anywhere. That said, you will find saprotrophic & parasitic fungi of varying types pretty much all over the world.

The possible fungus mentioned in the post you reference (Oyster Mushrooms) are in fact not parasitic, but consume already dead or dying material & are a choice edible!

But, (to the OP's knowledge), not found on non-hardwood species.

Comment: You are welcome! If I can be of further assistance (although I am clearly *not* a mushroom expert,) I am happy to be of assistance! 

Worth noting that not all mushrooms fall into the categories mentioned. Not all feed on dead & dying tissue, some are actually symbiotic, aka Ectomycorrhizal in nature & benefit both plant & fungus.

Comment: Some oyster mushroom species/strains will grow on conifers, but not nearly as many as will grow on hardwoods. (http://www.mushroomshack.com/all-about-mushrooms/mushroom-species/oyster)

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't thought of that with the Phoenix. Frankly I suspect that is what the mushroom growing on the Yucca is, but I can't find anything to support that conclusion...